# Is there any security risk if a malicious Microsoft Word (.doc) file is opened with the Apple Pages app?

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, ms-office, pages

An infected .doc file ([VirusTotal report](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/8d4a6a3f34ad31b697e8ada4cc3bcd4731b0206469daabff1d73deec48c339b7/detection)) was sent to a Mac via email and was opened with the Apple Pages app.

I did some research on my own and the only information I got is that a .doc file can cause damage by using macros when it is opened with the Microsoft Word app and macros are allowed. But the Apple Pages app doesn't support macros, so there shouldn't be a risk when it converts the .doc file to be able to open and display it.

Is there any other risk of a .doc file being harmful when it is opened with the Apple Pages app?

Comment: In all likelihood you are safe, Pages and MS Office don't share code, so the exploit would have to have been designed to work in pages. I'm not sure if any those exist in the wild—if they do, they're rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically *any* file can be a security risk if opened in an application, be it via malicious macros, be it via being tampered with to cause buffer overflows, be it somehow else.

Practically Pages can't run Word macros so opening Word documents in Pages should be safe.

Comment: Open open a .doc file in a plain text editor, or .docx files: change the extension from .docx to .zip, open the resultant zip archive and there will be text files and macro files and picture files and lots of xml to analyze. ...that is if you want to dig that deep.